# ElementRef offsetwidth always 0

Tags: d3.js, svg, angular7, ng-zorro-antd

I'm dealing with a problem, I need to get the element container width and height to properly render an svg inside. The thing is that OffsetWidth and Height are always 0 and I don't know what I'm missing.

Parent component:

```
<div nz-row [nzGutter]="16">
    <div nz-col nzSpan="24">
        <nz-card nzHoverable>
            <nz-range-picker [ngModel]="initialRange" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" nzShowTime nzFormat="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"></nz-range-picker>
            <bar-chart [data]="data"></bar-chart>
        </nz-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

bar chart component:

```
<div #chart class="chart-container"></div>
```

bar chart css:

```
.chart-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.chart-svg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

bar chart typescript:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'bar-chart',
    templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.scss']
})
export class BarChartComponent extends BaseChart implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('chart')
    private chartContainer: ElementRef;
    @Input()
    public data: DataModel[];
    public margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 };

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public ngOnInit() {
        if (!this.data) {
            return;
        }

        this.draw();
    }

    private draw(): void {
        d3.select('svg').remove();

        const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
        const data = this.data;

        const svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
            .attr('class', 'chart-svg')
            .attr('width', element.offsetWidth)
            .attr('height', element.offsetHeight);

        const contentWidth = element.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
        const contentHeight = element.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    }
}
```

I'm using ng-zorro-antd for UI design with angular 7.

Comment: does your browser's debugger say that your div has a non-zero width? I.e. does the div's parent have a non-zero size since it's sized to 100% of its parent/container.

Comment: The parent element is within an nz-card and I haven't specified any height on any element just the one I'm dealing with. If i'm not wrong, each component adjust to its content height

Comment: You've defined your container to be 100% of the height of its parent, not 100% of the height of its container.

Comment: thanks, so you mean I should define a fixed height to the nz-card component?

Comment: You could certainly try that couldn't you...

Comment: So I've tried what you've said, I've put a fixed height to nz-card and to a div within I applied a 100% height, but this isn't helping on returning offsetHeight and width for the svg element.

Comment: If you're trying to get offsetHeight of an SVG element that will return unknown as an SVG element is not a HTMLElement. See https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface I thought looking at the code you've provided that you were only trying to call offsetHeight on HTML elements though.

Comment: you were right, I'm calling the offsetHeight of the div containing the svg element, maybe I've expressed it wrong